# Regex of PostgreSQL Connection String

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am writing a regular expression for capturing the connection string of PostgreSQL. The format of the connection string as follows:

```
(postgresql|postgres)://[userspec@][hostspec][/dbname][?paramspec]

where userspec is: user[:password]
and hostspec is: [host][:port][,...]
and paramspec is: name=value[&...]
```

Here, the **userspec**, **port**, **dbname** and **paramspec** are optional.

The examples of the connection strings are as follows:

```
postgresql://localhost
postgresql://localhost:5433
postgresql://localhost/mydb
postgresql://user@localhost
postgresql://user:secret@localhost
postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?connect_timeout=10&application_name=myapp
postgresql://host1:123,host2:456/somedb?application_name=myapp
postgres://myuser:mypassword@192.168.0.100:5432/mydatabase
postgresql://192.168.0.100/mydb
```

I tried to formulate the below regular expression to capture the connection string and in addition capture the hostspec in a capturing group.

```
(postgresql|postgres):\/\/((?:[^:@]*)(?::[^@]*)?@{0,1})?(?<server>[^\/\?]+)\b
```

However, the regex could not capture properly when userspec is not present. The regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ux8BaZ/1).

Can you please point out on how to avoid the greedy evaluation of userspec and find the hostspec in each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are some corrections done on your regex to make it work as you expected.

- `(?:[^:@]*)` can be simplified to `[^:@]*`. You don't need to put it within brackets and then make it non-group using `?:` if you aren't doing anything with it as a group. Also added `\s` within it so it doesn't crawl to eat any newlines
- `(?::[^@]*)?` changed to `(?::[^@\s]*)?` to include `\s` for above reason
- `@{0,1}` changed to `@` as its needed. Also, you can write `@{0,1}` as simply `@?`
- Last in server group, `[^\/\?]+` changed to `[^\/\?\s]+` to again include `\s`

And with the above changes it seems to be working like you expected.

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ux8BaZ/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iZiUrJ/2)):

```
(postgres(?:ql)?):\/\/(?:([^@\s]+)@)?([^\/\s]+)(?:\/(\w+))?(?:\?(.+))?
```